# Derivatives and integrals in the Poynting theorem

Tags: electromagnetism, poynting-vector

Many derivations of the Poynting theorem follows the same approach:

The work done by the electromagnetic field is:

$dW = dq(\vec E + \vec v \times \vec B)\cdot d\vec l = dq(\vec E + \vec v \times \vec B)\cdot \vec v dt = dq (\vec E \cdot \vec v)dt$

Now, to calculate the work per volume unit, they divide both sides by $dV$. This is like taking derivatives with respect to volume in both sides:

$dW/dV = \rho(\vec E \cdot \vec v) dt$

I do not understand this last step. Why does only $dq$ is affected by $dV$ resulting in $\rho$?

If I have two functions $f$ and $g$,

$d(f\cdot g)/dV = df/dV\cdot g + f\cdot dg/dV$

I am not seen this procedure in this derivative in the Poynting theorem. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Dividing by $dV$ is not like deriving, because you're already dealing with differentials. It's not like you wrote an expression $W(V)$ and derived, you really divided $dW$ by $dV$.

Now, by definition, $dq = \rho dV $ , so dividing the right side by $dV$ will give you $\rho$ instead of $dq$.

Furthermore, remember that there is a hidden assumption here that you're dealing with such little volume elements that you can really define $\rho(\vec{r}) = \frac{dq}{dV} $ , and in these volumes $E$ and $v$ don't change much so they are pretty much constant.

Comment: If I had written $W = \int_c q(\vec E \cdot \vec v)dt$, where $c$ is the contour where I move the net charge $q$, then if I had taken time derivatives, $dW/dt = q(\vec E \cdot \vec v) = \iiint_V \rho dV \cdot (\vec E \cdot \vec v)$. If I take volumen derivative, would $d/dV(dW/dt) = \rho\vec E \cdot \vec v$? Would that approach have been exactly equivalent to the one I posted before?